# How to convert UUID/GUID to OID/DICOM UID in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, angular, dicom

How can I convert an UUID/GUID value like `8348d2c5-0a65-4560-bb24-f4f6bcba601d` (that I genreated with [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) v4) in to OID/DICOM UID like `2.25.174506987738820548334170905323706671133`? I would prefer the solution in JavaScript. See [wikipedia](https://wiki.ihe.net/index.php/Creating_Unique_IDs_-_OID_and_UUID)).

The example I converted with [this](https://www.igorkromin.net/?uuid=1) online generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58011693/5779732) from @AmitJoshi; I can now answer my question:

Here is the JavaScript function:

```
function GenerateUidFromGuid(){
   var guid = uuid.v4();                         //Generate UUID using node-uuid *) package or some other similar package
   var guidBytes = `0${guid.replace(/-/g, "")}`; //add prefix 0 and remove `-`
   var bigInteger = bigInt(guidBytes,16);        //As big integer are not still in all browser supported I use BigInteger **) packaged to parse the integer with base 16 from uuid string
   return `2.25.${bigInteger.toString()}`;       //Output the previus parsed integer as string by adding `2.25.` as prefix
}
```

Following are the references:

- https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid
- https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzyb0t9r/5/)

Answer (score 5):

I am aware you are looking for JavaScript sample; but following is a c# code. See if you can translate it to JavaScript. The variable names and data types are self explainer which may help you while translation.

The code below is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165940/5779732) answer from @VictorDerks. There is even a faster method explained in that answer; have a look.

```
public string GenerateUidFromGuid()
{
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    string strTemp = "";
    StringBuilder uid = new StringBuilder(64, 64);
    uid.Append("2.25.");

    //This code block is important------------------------------------------------
    string guidBytes = string.Format("0{0:N}", guid);
    BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.Parse(guidBytes, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    strTemp = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", bigInteger);
    uid.Append(strTemp);
    //This code block is important------------------------------------------------

    return uid.ToString();
}
```

The `Guid guid` looks like `f254934a-1cf5-47e7-913b-84431ba05b86`.

The `string.Format("0{0:N}", guid)` returns `0f254934a1cf547e7913b84431ba05b86`. Formatting is removed and prefixed with zero.

The `BigInteger.Parse(guidBytes....` returns `322112315302124436275117686874389371782`. The [`BigInteger.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Numerics_BigInteger_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_) will convert/parse the string to big-integer data type. The [`NumberStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.8) determine how to format.

Looking at the question, I think you are already aware about details explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46316162/5779732) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46316688/5779732).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want library that serves the same purpose, you may use [dicomuid.js](https://github.com/samucs/dicomuid.js) written by [samucs](https://github.com/samucs/dicomuid.js/commits?author=samucs) ([StackOverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4868258/samuel-salom%c3%a3o)).

This does not require organization root prefix; this uses "2.25." as prefix. This uses Universally Unique Identifier (UUID). It converts the UUID to a single large decimal number.

Following is the code copied from [github](https://github.com/samucs/dicomuid.js#getting-started):

```
// Create new DICOM UID.
// Result will be like 2.25.176371623884904210764200284661930180516
var uid1 = DICOMUID.create();

// Create DICOM UID from a RFC4122 v4 UUID.
// Result for line below is 2.25.329800735698586629295641978511506172918
var uid2 = DICOMUID.create("f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6");
```

Comment: Well, dicomuid.js is using internally (hardcoded) the same libraries (uuid.js and biginteger.js). I think using the needed libraries separately and writing a small function (like in my post) is a better solution.

Comment: @Sheki: No worries. I decided to add an answer just because I came across the library and this question was relevant. I am aware that you already found a solution. Just in case someone else prefer to use library instead of code, this may help.